# Is this sentence logical?

Tags: logic

Recently I came across this sentence:

> commercial air travel has revolutionized global tourism due to technological developments in jet aircrafts since the 1950s.

Is this sentence logical? I have been racking my brains to understand this. Is it because of commercial air travel or technological developments in jet aircrafts that global tourism has been revolutionized?

Commercial air travel ≠ technological developments in jet aircrafts. As one is air travel being commercialized while the other is about the development of aircrafts.

So, can someone tell me if the sentence is worded poorly or am I wrong?

Comment: The plural of 'aircraft' is, confusingly perhaps, 'aircraft'. _There are ten aircraft at the airport_.

Comment: Break it up. Commercial air travel has revolutionized global tourism. This is because of  technological developments in jet aircraft since the 1950s. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence makes two assertions, apart from a small grammar error (aircrafts) it is correct English.  In a formal logical structure you could write:

> Commercial jet travel has revolutionised global tourism.
> AND
> This revolution was caused by technological development.

The logical structure is just "P ∧ Q".  Which is true if and only if both P and Q are true.

You man *infer* that technological development allowed the development of commercial jet travel, which in turn revolutionised tourism.

To be honest, I don't know what you mean by "logical".  Logic is about the formal manipulation of propositions linked by logical operators like "AND" or "IMPLIES" and has very little to do with what can be inferred from context or general knowledge.

Comment: Sorry what I meant by logical is the meaning of it and not about its grammar. Maybe I used the wrong word. I think that the inference is right. Like lets say, 'he hit him because he was angry.' So the anger has allowed or pushed him to hitting him. The same could be applied here. I think my question is answered. I guess it was rather simple all along. Thanks for the help.